# Reading HSTORE columns from slave Postgres 9.3 Server

Tags: php, database, postgresql, zend-framework, psql

So I've got HSTORE up and running on my Master server, however on my two slaves whenever the application tries to query the slaves I get this error:

> Message: SQLSTATE[42704]: Undefined object: 7 ERROR: type "hstore"
>   does not exist

I've checked the PG slaves using `\DX` and both are showing `HSTORE` is installed, however whenever the app tries to read it gets the error above. :( HELP PLEASE :)

Comment: It may be because you have created the `HStore` extension in a different schema than your tables. You should always use this type precising the schema it belongs to.